# How to enable clipboard in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, clipboard

As we know to enable clipboard in Firefox user have to type 'about:config' in address bar and set 'signed.applets.codebase_principal_support' true. How make this is in Javascript? (user able to agree or disagree)

Comment: This is, luckily, not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can not.

Firefox doesn't even trust *you* in there (the *here be dragons* dialogue/warning).

However, you can use a [small Flash video](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) to enable copy to the clipboard handling in Firefox.

Comment: Zero Clipboard does not provide paste handling, just copying from the page to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

There is a W3C proposal for a [Clipboard API](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) and Mozilla is currently [working on implementing it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=407983). However, this work is still in early stages and it is unclear when it is supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Firefox doesn't give web developers a chance to present the user with a simple dialog to reduce their security settings.